# How to interpret odds ratio output for when there are multiple categorical dependent variables

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, odds-ratio

I am doing a project assessing whether a radiological abnormality called CSP is more common in brains of people with dementia compared to healthy controls. The size of the CSP is important so I have set up categories: small (0-3mm), medium (4-5mm), large (6mm+).

When I calculate the OR I put in the code:

```
epitools::oddsratio(d$Diagnosis, d$CSP.small.med.large., conf.level=0.95)
```

And get the output:

```
         Outcome
Predictor large medium small Total
  AD          5      7     9    21
  bv FTD      4      8    11    23
  Control     6      6    36    48
  Total      15     21    56    92

$measure
         odds ratio with 95% C.I.
Predictor  estimate     lower    upper
  AD      1.0000000        NA       NA
  bv FTD  1.4002600 0.2532507 8.195196
  Control 0.7272253 0.1332922 3.808998

$p.value
         two-sided
Predictor midp.exact fisher.exact chi.square
  AD              NA           NA         NA
  bv FTD   0.7001615   0.92556852 0.86612044
  Control  0.7068246   0.03122889 0.03252084

$correction
[1] FALSE

attr(,"method")
[1] "median-unbiased estimate & mid-p exact CI"
```

I am not sure how to interpret the odds ratios displayed in the table - with AD, bvFTD, control predictors vs the small medium and large CSP. Is it the odds of CSP of certain size for bvFTD vs AD, with AD set as 1 and then control vs AD, with AD set at 1?

Maybe the way I set up the test was inappropriate in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the code `oddsratio` in the package and found it really odd. For p-values, you are right, it takes the first row as a reference, and calculates p.values for it, for example, fisher.test of bv FTD vs AD and Control vs AD gives, what you see in the table:

```
M = matrix(c(5,4,6,7,8,6,9,11,36),ncol=3,
dimnames=list(c("AD","bv FTD","Control"),c("large","medium","small")))
fisher.test(M[1:2,1:3])$p.value
[1] 0.9255685
fisher.test(M[c(1,3),1:3])$p.value
[1] 0.03122889
```

However for odds ratio, it is only possible for 2x2, and I was wondering how it was calculated for in your case, 2x3, and in the code, they take only the first two columns, so for example in your case, odds ratio for bv FTD (1.4002600), it is calculated:

```
or.midp(M[1:2,1:2])
$x
       large medium
AD         5      7
bv FTD     4      8

$estimate
[1] 1.40026

$conf.int
[1] 0.2532507 8.1951963

$conf.level
[1] 0.95

attr(,"method")
[1] "median-unbiased estimate & mid-p exact CI"
```

The odds ratio is slightly different from that the raw estimate because they did some correct. Bottom line, the odds ratio is (large / medium in AD) / (large / medium in bv FTD).

I am not very sure if this is useful for you because it is only a subset of the matrix (ignoring the "small" column).